# setting domains

Tags: linux, bind, hosts

**EVERYTHING HAS BEEN SOLVED** - no need to answer :)

I'm setting a local webserver to do a lot of web development work from now on. I'm not really knowledgeable in hosting configuration.

Thing is I just added mydomain.com in /etc/hosts that's fine but what's the next step?

TI need to use the wildcard on *.mydomain.com, so I'm figuring I need to add my zone in bind, is this correct? so I can make use of virtual hosts in apache and in play-framework

Everything will be local, but once in a while I want to make public of my webserver to certain people using the no-ip service, in windows I've done it, in linux I don't know if it's any difference.

The question is pretty much if I'm configuring it right or not? If this sounds confusing let me know, I'll try to detail it more

Comment: Please post your solution and accept your answer, in order to close this question correctly.

Comment: My answer added, but I cannot choose it within two days... (says the system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up your own "local domain" you need to edit your `/etc/hosts` first, add your domain e.g `127.0.0.1   mydomain.com mydomain_alias` save your `/etc/hosts`.

After that you need to install bind and edit your named.conf, in this step I used `webmin` because it's so much easier than going through terminal. I added my master zone called `mydomain.com` and added the following addresses:

- www.mydomain.com
- *.mydomain.com
- test.mydomain.com

Next, we edit `/etc/default/bind9`, be sure `RESOLVCONF=yes` is there, else add it. To disable ipv6 **believe me you might want to because in your system logs it starts trying to figure out ipv6 of requests**. So make it IpV4 only,

End result might look like this, whereas `-4` refers to the internet protocol version

```
OPTIONS="-4 -u bind"
```

Once you configure bind properly you are almost ready to go.

Next step, edit your `/etc/resolv.conf`

Put `nameserver 127.0.0.1` as the very first of your nameservers. Now to test your wildcard, set up apache, set virtual hosts *google for more reference*

Simple example:

```
<VirtualHost *>

   ServerName www.mydomain.com
   ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
   DocumentRoot /path/to/documentroot
</VirtualHost>
```

Enjoy, any doubts just comment